# Thinking about adding a Keyboard tray to a MDF Desk, is it safe?

Tags: desk

So I am thinking of buying this Desk ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07MQDPP38/ref=ox_sc_act_title_4?smid=A1N6DT631H7VR6&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MQDPP38))

And these sliding arms ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00AHFRUHE/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A3K6XLR8HSJJOI&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AHFRUHE))

For the time being I would be using my current leftover tray from a desk I am using right now.

That desk on Amazon says it uses MDF, would it be safe for gaming? I am not sure how well MDF handles screws or weight from hands/wrists resting.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question; if one of these answers help you, please click the checkmark next to the best. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

If you use coarse threaded screws specifically engineered for MDF and use all the mounting holes available to you, the load distribution should be good enough for the desk. If you really want the belt-and-suspenders approach, consider to mount the sliding arms to a pair of one-by-twos or a sheet of plywood, then glue and screw them to the MDF. This will most certainly prevent pull-out of the screws holding the arms, as well as provide for longer screws if you consider that you now have the thickness of the one-by-twos or the plywood added to the thickness of the MDF. If you plan to screw into the MDF, pre-drill and use screws that will not puncture the top. MDF likes to dislodge if the screw tip gets too close to the surface.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question but I think the answer is yes because the desk goes over a 90-degree corner and that gives you shearing support to rest your arms on the tray. If that does not work there is an easy workaround. Just add small 90 angles against the walls from below to fix the backside if you can. MDF should hold the screws but predrill and be careful to not screw all the way through and use bigger screws.